# Calling a variadic function in a Jenkinsfile fails unpredictably

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, variadic-functions, jenkins-groovy, gstring

## Context

I'm running Jenkins on Windows, writing declarative pipelines. I'm trying to put multiple commands in a single `bat` step, while still making the step fail if any of the included commands fail.

Purpose of this is twofold.

- The best practices document suggests that creating a step for every little thing might not be the best idea (might also be solved by putting more stuff in batch files, but my builds aren't that big yet)
- I want to execute some commands in a Visual Studio command prompt, which is achieved by first `call`ing a `.bat` file that sets the environment, and then doing any necessary commands.

## Code

I wrote the following Groovy code in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
def ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps(String... steps)
{
    bat ConcatenateMultipleCmdSteps(steps)
}

String ConcatenateMultipleCmdSteps(String... steps)
{
    String[] commands = []
    steps.each { commands +="echo ^> Now starting: ${it}"; commands += it; }
    return commands.join(" && ")
}
```

## The problem/question

I can't get this to work reliably. That is, in a single `Jenkinsfile`, I can have multiple calls to `ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps()`, and some will work as intended, while others will fail with `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps' found among steps [addBadge, ...`

I have not yet found any pattern in the failures. I thought it only failed when executing from within a `warnError` block, but now I also have a problem from within a `dir()` block, while in a different `Jenkinsfile`, that works fine.

This problem seems to be related to `ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps()` being a variadic function. If I provide an overload with the correct number of arguments, then that overload is used without problem.

I'm at a loss here. Your input would be most welcome.

## Failed solution

At some point I thought it might be a scoping/importing thing, so I enclosed `ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps()` in a class (code below) as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39830673/114197). Now, the method is called as `Helpers.ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps()`, and that results in a `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: No such static method found: staticMethod Helpers ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl`

```
public class Helpers {
    public static environment

    public static void ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps(String... steps)
    {
        environment.bat ConcatenateMultipleCmdSteps(steps)
    }

    public static String ConcatenateMultipleCmdSteps(String... steps)
    {
        String[] commands = []
        steps.each { commands +="echo ^> Now starting: ${it}"; commands += it; }
        return commands.join(" && ")
    }
```

## Minimal failing example

Consider the following:

```
hello = "Hello"

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Stage") {
            steps {
                SillyEcho("Hello")
                SillyEcho("${hello}" as String)
                SillyEcho("${hello}")
            }
        }
    }
}

def SillyEcho(String... m)
{
    echo m.join(" ")
}
```

I'd expect all calls to `SillyEcho()` to result in `Hello` being echoed. In reality, the first two succeed, and the last one results in `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'SillyEcho' found among steps [addBadge, addErrorBadge,...`

## Curiously succeeding example

Consider the following groovy script, pretty much equivalent to the failing example above:

```
hello = "Hello"

SillyEcho("Hello")
SillyEcho("${hello}" as String)
SillyEcho("${hello}")

def SillyEcho(String... m)
{
    println m.join(" ")
}
```

When pasted into a Groovy Script console (for example the one provided by Jenkins), this succeeds (`Hello` is printed three times).

Even though I'd expect this example to succeed, I'd also expect it to behave consistently with the failing example, above, so I'm a bit torn on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for adding the failing and succeeding examples.
I expect your issues are due to the incompatibility of `String` and `GString`.

With respect to the differences between running it as a pipeline job and running the script in the Jenkins Script Console, I assume based on this that the Jenkins Script Console is not as strict with type references or tries to cast parameters based upon the function signature. I base this assumption on this script, based upon your script:

```
hello = "Hello"
hello2 = "${hello}" as String
hello3 = "${hello}"

println hello.getClass()
println hello2.getClass()
println hello3.getClass()

SillyEcho(hello)
SillyEcho(hello2)
SillyEcho(hello3)

def SillyEcho(String... m)
{
    println m.getClass()
}
```

This is the output I got in the Jenkins Script Console:

```
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.String
class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
class [Ljava.lang.String;
class [Ljava.lang.String;
class [Ljava.lang.String;
```

I expect the pipeline doesn't cast the `GString` to `String` but just fails as there is no function with the `Gstring` as parameter.

For debugging you could try to invoke `.toString()` an all elements you pass on to your function.

**Update**

This seems to be a known issue (or at least reported) with the pipeline interpreter: [JENKINS-56758](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-56758).

In the ticket an extra work-around has been described using collections instead of varargs. This would omit the need to type-cast everything.

Comment: The language spec claims that Groovy will typically cast between GString and String (as is shown in the ScriptConsole example. Pipeline seems to do so only for non-variadic functions. I'm beginning to consider that omission a bug. So for now, I guess your advice to cast explicitly is the best we can do. Even though I don't very much like the way it clutters the code. https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gstrings

Comment: Indeed, this seems to be a bug in the Jenkins pipeline interpreter.
I have added a link to the bug report in my answer.

It also contains another work-around using Collections instead of varargs.

Comment: Thanks for digging up that issue report. I've been meaning to do that myself

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will answer your question, if not, consider it as a bigger comment.
I like how you borrowed the 'variadic functions' from C++ :)
However, in groovy there is much elegant way how to deal with this.

Try this:

```
def ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps(steps)
{
    sh steps
        .collect { "echo \\> Now starting: $it && $it" }
        .join(" && ")
}        

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage ("test") {
            steps {
                ExecuteMultipleCmdSteps(["pwd", "pwd"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which works just fine for me:

```
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestJob
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo > Now starting: pwd
> Now starting: pwd
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestJob
+ echo > Now starting: pwd
> Now starting: pwd
+ pwd
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TestJob
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

You may want to rewrite your function like this.
The 2 errors you mention may have different causes.

The fist one, "No such DSL method ..." is indeed a scoping one, you found yourself the solution, but I do not understand why the overload works in the same scope.

The second error, may be solved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46762126/5595263). However, for me your code from the second approach works also just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Your solution is much more elegant than mine, so I'll use it to improve my code.

It does nothing, though, to fix my problem. I've added a "minimal failing example" as well as a "curiously succeeding example" to my question to further narrow down the problem I'm having.